# Text in HTML Table is a incorrectly a clickable "event" in WKWebview

Tags: html, ios, xcode, webview

I have an issue I've not been able to find a solution for a long time. Please bear with me if I am not using the correct terminology. I am relatively new to software development and very new to iOS.

Basically I have a list of numbers in an HTML table displayed in a webview and some of them, apparently randomly, are displayed in bold text and allows me to click on them to create an "event" within iOS. This should not be the case. No data should be clickable or generate an even with a press.

I've included a screenshot and a snippet of my html code. Any assistance is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
            <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

            </button>
            <style>
                th {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
                }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background: #DBE8F9;
            }
            </style>
            </head>

<body>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <input id="filterTable-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search For Material...">
                </form>
        <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow" id="myTable" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-priority="1">Material</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">lb/ft<sup>&sup3;</sup></th>
                    <th data-priority="1">g/cm<sup>&sup3;</sup></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aluminum Hydroxide </td> <!--item in question from screenshot-->
                        <td>26.5 </td>
                        <td>0.42</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aluminum Oxide </td>
                        <td>36 </td>
                        <td>0.58</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aluminum Silicate </td>
                        <td>31 </td>
                        <td>0.5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
             </tbody>
             </table>

         </div>

    <div data-role="footer" align="center">

        <a href="javascript:void(0)"   onclick="parent.window.scrollTo(0,0);">Back to Top</a>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very odd...

Some quick testing, and it appears that when you adjacent table cells match this format:

```
dd.mm hh.mm
```

it is ***often but not always*** detected as a date. So,

```
26.5 0.42 == May 26th
26.10 5.12 == October 26th
```

If you disable Calendar Event data detection on your `WKWebView`, those won't be detected. Of course, any actual dates that you *want* to be detected won't work either.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on the internal parsing code... Probably could find it for Swift, but that wouldn't help much anyway.